# Calling Laravel controller method from another controller method with redirect

Tags: laravel, redirect, controller

I have a Laravel 4 app with a database of listings that I want to revalidate every 30 days. The revalidation process is fairly complex, and it redirects to various blades based on result. So far, I've been clicking manually on each one to revalidate, and I want to create a batch function to validate all.

Here's my working revalidate function (simplified), with the new batchValidate function:

```
public function revalidate($id=null,$batch=null)
{
    $citation = Citation::findOrFail($id);
    // Check a bunch of stuff

    if( X fails){
        return View::make('citations.manualRevalidateA');
    }
    if( Y fails){
        return View::make('citations.manualRevalidateB');
    }
    if( Z fails){
        return View::make('citations.manualRevalidateC');
    }

    if(!empty($batch) && $batch=='batch'){

        return array(
            'nap_status'=>$napcheck[0],
            'nap_details'=>$napcheck[1],
            'cache'=>$napcheck[2],
        );

    return Redirect::to('citations/')
        ->with('flash-success','Validation successful');
}

public function batchValidate()
{

    $citations = Citation::getAll();

    foreach ($citations as $citation) {
        $data=$this->revalidate($citation->id,'batch');

        // Store the result
    }

    return Redirect::to('citations/')
    ->with('flash-success','Batch validation has completed successfully.);
}
```

If revalidate() encounters an error, I do want the loop to stop and control to go to one of the manualRevalidate blades. But my syntax

```
        return View::make('citations.manualRevalidateC');
```

is causing it to return to the batchValidate function with all the compressed data for the view instead of the result array I wanted.

I'm sure this is a simple Laravel syntax issue, but how to go call the manualRevalidate blades **without** returning to my batch function?

Comment: Are these `citations.manualRevalidateA`,`citations.manualRevalidateB`,`citations.manualRevalidateC` **types** of manual revalidations and are very few in number?

Comment: A cheap solution is to remove the `return` and add a `die`.

Comment: Or a proper one can be to set these blade names in a `config/citations_manual_revalidate.php` file and make the method to return `mixed` values - either `false` or an `array`. If method returns an array, you can continue the execution, else, have an `instance` variable and set it's value to one of the blade strings and return the view accordingly.

Comment: @vivek_23, they are different types of manual revalidations, which use the same blade but with different data. I don't want to add a die; they need to go to the manualRevalidate blade for further input.

Comment: I actually don't want to continue execution at that point; I want it to go to the manualRevalidate blade. Since the revalidate() function is called by clicking on a link, return seems to have no problem generating the blade. But if I call revalidate() from another method in the controller, return does not generate the blade.

Comment: Is there another way to open a view from the controller without using "return"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further research, I was not able to find any way to route the application flow the way I wanted to in Laravel. Essentially, if I call a method from another method inside a controller, I cannot call a view without first returning to the original method, because Laravel uses "return" to generate the view (i.e., returning from the Controller to a blade).

So, my approach was to take all the logic that was in the revalidate() function in the controller and put it in a method in the model. The model then returns the result to the controller. I **can** call the model method from both controller methods, and then route from there to the appropriate blades.

Answer (score 1):

- For a good design, keep blade names in a separate config file, because you might use it later in other files as the application grows and you would want to have a single point of management.
- Make a new file in `config` folder with name(any name of your choice), say `citations_manual_revalidate.php`. Make an array having key-value pairs where `key` is a meaningful name you want to keep and `value` being the blade name.

**config/citations_manual_revalidate.php:**

```
<?php


return array(
    'manualRevalidateA' => 'citations.manualRevalidateA'
    'manualRevalidateB' => 'citations.manualRevalidateB',
    'manualRevalidateC' => 'citations.manualRevalidateC'
);
```

- Since your methods are in a class, we will have an instance variable which will hold the view to be loaded, if any test fails.
- In your **revalidate()** method, we will return `mixed` values, i.e, either a `false` or an `array()`. While doing so, we will also set the value of the instance variable (which is **citation_view** in below code) to the view to be loaded and `return false`.
- So, this way, we will know in our method **batchValidate()** as to which view needs to be loaded if any test fails and return them.

**CitationManager.php:**

```
<?php

use Config;

class CitationManager{
    private $citation_view;

    public function revalidate($id=null,$batch=null){
        $citation = Citation::findOrFail($id);
        // Check a bunch of stuff

        if( X fails){
            $this->citation_view = Config::get('citations_manual_revalidate.manualRevalidateA');
            return false;
        }
        if( Y fails){
            $this->citation_view = Config::get('citations_manual_revalidate.manualRevalidateB');
            return false;
        }
        if( Z fails){
            $this->citation_view = Config::get('citations_manual_revalidate.manualRevalidateC');
            return false;
        }

        $this->citation_view = ''; // reset this since there is no failure.

        if(!empty($batch) && $batch=='batch'){
            return array(
                'nap_status'=>$napcheck[0],
                'nap_details'=>$napcheck[1],
                'cache'=>$napcheck[2],
            );
        }

        return array(
            // with whatever details you want to send
        );
    }

    public function batchValidate(){

        $citations = Citation::getAll();

        foreach ($citations as $citation) {
            $data = $this->revalidate($citation->id,'batch');
            if($data === false){
                return View::make($this->citation_view);
            }else{
                // some processing
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('citations/')
        ->with('flash-success','Batch validation has completed successfully.');
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I used a similar method to work around my issue.

Comment: @MrMoxy Great. In that case, you may answer your question and accept it if you like since it would best suit your case.